# PayPalRESTException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have tried many ways but i am always getting the same exception, PayPalRESTException: Connection timed out: connect . I have even downloaded sample code provided by paypal and tried using those code, but still same error.
Please help me to come out from this problem. or at least provide your opinion.

Error Log :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [signup] in context with path [/PayPalDemo] threw exception [com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException: Connection timed out: connect] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.core.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:93)
    at com.paypal.core.rest.OAuthTokenCredential.generateOAuthToken(OAuthTokenCredential.java:132)
    at com.paypal.core.rest.OAuthTokenCredential.generateAccessToken(OAuthTokenCredential.java:95)
    at com.paypal.core.rest.OAuthTokenCredential.getAccessToken(OAuthTokenCredential.java:86)
    at com.paypal.util.AccessTokenGenerator.getAccessToken(AccessTokenGenerator.java:20)
    at com.paypal.util.AppHelper.createCreditCard(AppHelper.java:54)
    at com.paypal.controller.UserServlet.handleSignup(UserServlet.java:268)
    at com.paypal.controller.UserServlet.doPost(UserServlet.java:117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have visited several blogs also for figure out this problem but they suggested to check request URL.

I am using sendbox environment so i have provided following url :

https://api.sandbox.paypal.com

This is my SDK configuration file :

```
# Connection Information
http.ConnectionTimeOut=5000
http.Retry=1
http.ReadTimeOut=30000
http.MaxConnection=100

# HTTP Proxy configuration
# If you are using proxy set http.UseProxy to true and replace the following values with your proxy parameters
http.UseProxy=false
#http.ProxyPort=8080
#http.ProxyHost=127.0.0.1
#http.ProxyUserName=null
#http.ProxyPassword=null

#Set this property to true if you are using the PayPal SDK within a Google App Engine java app
http.GoogleAppEngine = false

# Service Configuration
service.EndPoint=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com
clientID=EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp (changed my own)
clientSecret=EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp (changed my own)
```

Servlet File :

```
package com.paypal.api.payments.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.paypal.api.payments.Address;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Amount;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Authorization;
import com.paypal.api.payments.CreditCard;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Details;
import com.paypal.api.payments.FundingInstrument;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Payer;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Payment;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Transaction;
import com.paypal.api.payments.util.GenerateAccessToken;
import com.paypal.core.rest.APIContext;
import com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException;
import com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalResource;

public class GetAuthorizationServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
            .getLogger(GetAuthorizationServlet.class);

    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {

        InputStream is = GetAuthorizationServlet.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties");
        try {
            System.out.println("in read::");
            PayPalResource.initConfig(is);
        } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.fatal(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        APIContext apiContext = null;
        String accessToken = null;
        try {
            accessToken = GenerateAccessToken.getAccessToken();
            System.out.println("Access Token ::"+accessToken);

        } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            req.setAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        req.getRequestDispatcher("response.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

}
```

Utility file that will get token from paypal

```
package com.paypal.util;

import com.paypal.core.ConfigManager;
import com.paypal.core.rest.OAuthTokenCredential;
import com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException;

public class AccessTokenGenerator {
    private static String accessToken;

    public static String getAccessToken() throws PayPalRESTException {
        if (accessToken == null) {

            // ClientID and ClientSecret retrieved from configuration
            String clientID = ConfigManager.getInstance().getValue("clientID");
            String clientSecret = ConfigManager.getInstance().getValue("clientSecret");
            accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret).getAccessToken();
        }
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem continuously since last 9 hrs but now i found the solution.
There is no error in code implementation but my firewall was not let them go to connect.

When i was turned off my firewall from control panel then all code works perfectly.

Thanks you